# Services don't get called after changing its endpoint address in Silverlight under ServiceRefrences.ClientConfig file

Tags: silverlight-5.0, service-reference, wcf-endpoint

I created a Silverlight application, calling services for database connection. I need to deploy this application on to another server. And i made one change in ServiceRefrences.ClientConfig file. I changed the endpoint address to `<endpoint address="http://ServerName/Service.svc">`from `<endpoint address="http://localhost/InsertService.svc">` as the requirement is to access through Servername.
Now the question is, after changing endpoint address from "localhost" to "ServerName", its not working. Services are not getting called and hence fails to connect to Database. Any idea/help/advice on this would truly be appreciated.
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to i was placing the published folder into different location. http://ServerName/.... was being accessed in d:\ drive while i was copying the folder into c:\ drive. Also it seems the server was accessed by quite a few ppl simulatneously hence due to load it used to take time to call the service, resulting in time-out operation... 
I hope the post gets helpful.
Thanks